# generating a sequence of random numbers unique on every run of same input

Tags: java, random, numbers, unique

Given is a list of names suppose a,b,c,d.
I want to generate secret santas of these names
allowed output is as follows..

```
name secretsanta
a      b
b      d
c      a
d      c
```

Note:any output is valid except if we get same secret santa for more than one name i.e

```
a->a
b->a
c->d
d->b
```

the above is not allowed

Also if I get a correct output for an input once and run it again with same input I should not get the same result again i.e
    a->b
    b->d
    c->a
    d->c
This should not repeat immediately. It is allowed to get repeated only after a different output gets displayed at least once after that.

Following is the code I tried:

```
do
{
    total_size=ss.santa.size();     
    Collections.shuffle(ss.santa);
    System.out.println("Below is the list of names with their secret santas");
    System.out.println("Participant    Secret Santa");
    Iterator<?> itr=ss.names.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        String name=(String)itr.next(); 
        String SecretName;
        do
        {
            int rand=r.nextInt(total_size);
            SecretName=ss.santa.get(rand);          
        }while(name.equals(SecretName) || s.contains(SecretName) );
        s.add(SecretName);
        System.out.println(name+"    "+SecretName);         
    }

    s.removeAll(ss.names);
    Collections.shuffle(ss.santa);
    System.out.println("do you want to rerun??");
    System.out.println(" 1-YES 2-NO");
    choice=scn.nextInt();
}while(choice==1);
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: @EricStein, you stole my comment!

Comment: It printed correct output once but during rerun it printed incomplete output and the program hung

Comment: that what you are doing is very risky, imagine situation when you have 3 names A,B,C. A picked B, B picked A, and whoever you picked for C will be already in your `s` list, or it will be C himself, which means your program will hung there

Answer (score 1):

Modifying [a shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) for this purpose is rather easy: (copied from the Java API, just decreased the range of the random generator by one to exclude keeping an element in the same spot, i.e. changed `rnd.nextInt(i)` to `rnd.nextInt(i-1)`, and removed some code)

```
public static void swap(List<?> list, int i, int j) {
   final List l = list;
   l.set(i, l.set(j, l.get(i)));
}

public static void shuffle(List<?> list) {
   Random rnd = new Random();
   for (int i = list.size(); i > 1; i--)
      swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i-1));
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
   List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
   System.out.println(input);
   shuffle(input);
   System.out.println(input);
}
```

Now the fact that you want unique outputs on every run is a bit more difficult. This actually points to a deterministic algorithm, rather than a random one. Though it can also easily (although not particularly efficiently) be done as follows: (using the same `shuffle` function as above)

```
Set<List> set = new HashSet<List>();
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
set.add(input);
int amountToGenerate = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < amountToGenerate; i++)
{
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(input);
    do
    {
        shuffle(temp);
    }
    while (set.contains(temp));
    System.out.println(temp);
    set.add(temp);
}
```

Although this will lend itself to the possibility of one person getting the same secret santa many times in a row, even though the whole set is unique.